# Override "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Does anyone know if its possible to override this dialog on ios safari when trying to open a native app from the safari browser using a URI `appname:///` and the app is not installed on a device?

I tried overriding the `window.alert` and it works as expected for browser alerts, however it does not work when this pops up. Or does this maybe fire some event that I can listen for using `window.addEventListener()`?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Having a similar problem here. Thanks!